# asp.net Repeater auto set index

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I'm new for asp.net and now using control asp:Repeater.
I want to implement follow table by Repeater:

```
            index             Name           Delete

              1               DDD              X

              2               EEE              X

              3               FFF              X
```

Now the index is auto generate by set <%# (Container.ItemIndex+1) %> in asp.net page.

My question is below:

when I click 'X' to remove TableRow by JS method. How to make the column index value refresh? But sadly, the column idx become below:

```
              index           Name           Delete

              1               DDD              X

              3               FFF              X
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're removing it via a javascript. just hook into that and add a piece of code that reseeds your indices

```
// sample reseeding code
$('button').on('click', function() {

    $(this).closest('tr').remove();

    $('table').find('tbody').find('tr').each(function(i) {
        // update the value of the index column
        $(this).find('td').first().text(i + 1);
    });
});
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/7fbnn95a/

Answer (score 1):

> when I click 'X' to remove TableRow by register Js method

If it's JS , then you're out of C# code.

so your question should also be tagged as JS/jQuery.

regarding :

```
How to make the column index value refresh ?
```

My solution using jQuery is  :

```
$("#t tr td:nth-child(1)").on('click',function (i,n){ 
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();

    $("#t tr td:nth-child(1)").each(function (i,n){$(this).text(i+1)})                         

})
```

[image]

http://jsbin.com/hutefo/3/edit